# Google Play allows publishers to respond to users' comments?

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

As far as I have known, and also read in the description of many apps on Google Play, it is not possible for publishers to respond to user's comments, but recently I have come across this:

[image]

Can someone give me more info on this? Also, if a publisher responds to my comment, how would I be notified about this? I do not see any Inbox or anything of that sort, also there's no option where we "Allow" Google Play to send up e-mails.

Comment: "also there's no option where we "Allow" Google Play to send up e-mails." LOL. It's not a box. It's the terms-of-service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, developers can reply to a user review. The user will get a notification via email.

However, as of now this feature is only available for "those with a Top Developer badge." So not all developers can reply to your comments.

Read [this page from Android Developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/06/replying-to-user-reviews-on-google-play.html) for more details.