# Where can I see if a developer responded to my comment on the Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

It appears that Google is allowing some developers to respond to Google Play application comments.

Here is a [blog post explaining the feature.](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/06/replying-to-user-reviews-on-google-play.html)

Let's assume I posted a comment on an app and the developer responded to me.

How does it look like ? How can I acknowledge the fact that he responded ?

Do I get a notification ? An email ? Nothing ?

Comment: As your comment is connected to your account, there are two options: 1) you get a mail via GMail, or 2) you get some G+ stuff (no idea what, as a) I don't use G+, and b) no longer leave comments as that would force me to G+).

Answer (score 3):

OK, I came across a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33064/google-play-allows-publishers-to-respond-to-users-comments?rq=1).

It looks like you will get an email if a developer responded to your comment.