# Where in the Play Store can I see reaction from an app developer

Tags: google-play-store, feedback

I recently sent private feedback to the developers of *Microsoft Launcher (Beta)*, using the app's Feedback option (Options > Help and Feedback > Send feedback).

Now, a few days later, I got a notification from the Play Store that the developer responded, but I can't find the response anywhere. What I do see is this:

- Open Play Store
- Click on my profile picture, and select *Offers and Notifications*
- Select the *Notifications* tab. There's one entry that says: *Reaction from the developer on your review: View the response, and update your review for Microsoft Launcher*:

  [image: Notificationss tab]
- Clicking on this entry opens the app's information page in the Play Store, but not my message, nor the developer's response.

  [image: Info page]

Where can I find the developer's response? It seems to be integrated in Play Store?

This [old question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/where-can-i-see-if-a-developer-responded-to-my-comment-on-the-google-play) suggests that an email is sent, but I can't find anything (not in the spam folder either)

If it makes a difference, this is an old phone with Android 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer already. When using a newer phone with Android 11, I do see my own feedback *and* the developer's response.

Not even having Microsoft Launcher installed on that phone, I can search the Play Store for it, and on the app's information page (2nd screenshot in my question) I see the information I was looking for.