# Google Play: "Developer has responded to your review" notification but no response

Tags: google-play-store

These questions

- [Where can I see if a developer responded to my comment on the Google Play?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37397/where-can-i-see-if-a-developer-responded-to-my-comment-on-the-google-play)
- [Google Play allows publishers to respond to users' comments?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33064/google-play-allows-publishers-to-respond-to-users-comments)

Are very old, but they both suggest that I would get an email when a developer responds.

I have not received an email, but I did get a notification on my phone "Developer has responded to your review". I clicked the notification and got taken through to the app that I recently reviewed.

I can see my review, but no developer response.

So where has the developer response gone?! Is there a way I can see it?

Comment: Possibly related: [Where in the Play Store can I see reaction from an app developer](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246290/44325) (2022)

Comment: Yes that looks like the same issue, though their issue was solved by updating their phone to Android 11. I'm already on Android 11 (as well as upgrading an operating system not being a satisfactory answer!)

Comment: This is insanely frustrating. If you "view all reviews" and scroll until you see yours, you will see the developer response. But sometimes that takes forever or you just don't find yours.  Why the $#@& is the response not visible under "your review" on the main page... The one the notification takes you to?!

Comment: @THEJOATMON I have noticed that as well.  I consider Google's Play Store to be a bug-filled disaster with horrible UX.  I recommend using F-Droid whenever you can, and communicate directly with open-source developers in their public code repositories.

Comment: So this happened to me last night and when I clicked the Android notification I was actually taken directly to my review and could see the developer's response. I'm not sure if this was a fluke or if they changed something. Will see if it happens again.